# Matplotlib with Frequency of strings

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, bar-chart

Ok So I am trying to create a "prettier" graph than the one I have in R.  I am wondering if there is any easy way to use frequency in one column and strings in another.  All of the documentation I have found seems not to touch on this subject other than xticks.  In R this is rather simple so I feel like I am missing something here.

In R I can simply do this:

```
> data<-read.table ("/home/myname/Desktop/hist.txt", sep="|")
> names (data)[2] = "Words"
> names (data)[1] = "Frequency"
> barplot(data$Frequency)
```

Where my data is structured as such:

```
3059195|and
2066278|ant
1851521|it
1741203|was
```

I could just assign numbers to the words and then set the as tickmarks but I am trying to avoid unnecessary workarounds.

Would anyone have a good minimal example?

Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('/home/shulby/Desktop/hist.txt','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Words')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Balanced Histogram')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I am just not sure how to treat "y" here.

Comment: Can you upload your R plot or desired plot? Your R code will give 4 bars with the same height 1, which have X label as the number (3059195 ...) and have y from 0 to 1. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('/home/shulby/Desktop/hist.txt','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    for row in plots:
        y.append(int(row[0]))

N = len(y)
x = range(N)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Words')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Balanced Histogram')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```